# Getting Error while initializing Terraform with version 1.1

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to migrate my local state file to TF Cloud by following this link :

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cloud-migrate?in=terraform/cloud

I already have my workspace and i have logged in to TF Cloud from the CMD Line using the API token that i got. My code is shown below

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
  required_providers {
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "3.0.1"
    }
  }
  cloud {
    organization = "Pallab-Training"
    workspaces {
      name = "terraform-azurerm-networking"
    }
  }
}





/* terraform {
  required_providers {
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "3.0.1"
    }
  }
  required_version = "~> 1.0"
} */

variable "name_length" {
  description = "The number of words in the pet name"
  default     = "3"
}

resource "random_pet" "pet_name" {
  length    = var.name_length
  separator = "-"
}

output "pet_name" {
  value = random_pet.pet_name.id
}
```

But i get the  error constantly as attached. I am trying to use Terraform 1.1
Any idea why this error is coming even though i am following the tutorial as it is[image]

Comment: Can you double check your version: `tf -version`?

Comment: @Marcin Oh it is 1.0.0. Is that the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cloud` is not supported in v1.0. From [docs](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cloud-migrate?in=terraform/cloud):

> Because the cloud block is not supported by older versions of Terraform, you must use **1.1.0 or higher** in order to follow this tutorial.

You have to **upgrade** your TF.